# Rename table name in MS SQL server. Required to change

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to rename table name in MS SQL Server. I have created table. Required to change table name in MS SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: There are plenty of resources out there if you just Google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+table+name+in+MS+SQL+Server. Is there a particular problem you're having that we can help with?

Comment: I suppose right clicking the table name and selecting rename isn't what you are looking for...

Comment: @Tanner Not if it's part of a series of schema changes wrapped in one transaction.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sp_rename`:

```
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.old_table_name', 'new_table_name';
```

This is assuming your table resides in schema `dbo`.